# Reduce bandwidth using Puppeteer and Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I've created a function such as:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const cors      = require('cors')({origin: true});

exports.exploreLinks = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    
    return cors(request, response, async () => {
        
        const root = request.body.url;
        
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});

        /* ... More code here ... */
        
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        
        await browser.close();
        
        response.json(result);  
        
    });
    
});
```

After deploying the function, bandwidth is increasing by ~170 MB on each deployment (deployed 2 times today so far):

[image: Bandwidth Firebase]

Since I'm testing the function, I need to deploy the function several times per day and I would like to lower the bandwidth.

I've tried to deploy the function such as:

```
# Instead of using firebase deploy --only functions
# I deploy a specific function

firebase deploy --only functions:exploreLinks
```

But it's still using a lot of bandwidth. Is there a way to reduce the bandwidth on each deployment?

Comment: Deploying a function should not change the amount of bandwidth it consumes.  Bandwidth is consumed when a function is invoked by a client.  Contact Firebase support directly if you have concerns about the accuracy of what you see in the console.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support